# Twitter bootstrap call the ajax more than 1 times

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.3.1 to popup modal. Content of modal is a form (non remote). I am using ajax to insert the value in database.

My problem is, If I open the form and close it and then again open it then on submitting the form the ajax is called twice (I can see in console).

my modal is bind with element (button) which is dynamically generated multiple time inside datatable.

Below is my js code

```
$("#datatable").on('click', '.my-button', function(){

                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                $('#myModal').modal('show');                

                $('.btn-close-modal').on('click', function() {                          
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                });

                $('.btn-save-changes').on('click', function() {

                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');


                    var rmk = $('#remark').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'add-value.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { id: id, rm: rmk },
                        success: function(a) {

                        }
                    });
                });
});
```

Below is my modal code

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close btn-close-modal" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Form</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->

                <!-- form start -->
                <form role="form" method="post">                        
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Remark</label>                                
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="remark" name="remark" >

                            </div><!-- /.form group -->                         

                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->  

                </form>
            </div><!-- /.box -->
         </div>
        </div> <!--/.row--->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-close-modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-save-changes">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried all these below code, but they did not work

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myModal').removeData();
})

$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});

$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});

$( '#myModal' ).modal( 'hide' ).data( 'bs.modal', null );
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the click method for .btn-save-changes outside of the #datatable click method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that the form is posting once for each time $('#datatable').on() is called. Try separating out the jQuery for showing/hiding the modal and posting the form, something like:

```
$('#datatable').on('click', function () {
    // show the modal
});

$('.btn-close-modal').on('click', function () {
    // hide the modal
});

$('.btn-save-changes').on('click', function () {
    // ajax
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will try. Any easy way to get the value from $('#datatable') click in ajax ? See my js code, I am receiving id of clicked element and passing it through ajax

Comment: what kind of element is #datatable? Is it a table with several clickable items in it or a form control? By your HTML I'm guessing it's outside of the modal...

Comment: You could declare a global variable and set it equal to the element id in the same way you're currently assigning the value. Or in your js where you set var id you could instead add a class 'clicked' or something unique, then when you're saving changes you could retrieve the id using the unique class name

Comment: Sorry for late response. You are right, after separating the jquery code it fixed my problem. For id, I just saved the value in extra hidden input field on click event. Thank you very much for the help.